# admin-ajax.php not loading anymore

Tags: ajax

I'm working on wordpress 3.6. Everything was fine but previous to launching the site the administrator changed the domain name. Everything remained in the same server. We didn't have to move any files, and all the files and folder stayed on the same relative positions they were before.

To take care of the change in domain name I updated the databases with the [Search & Replace DB](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) script and everything is working well on the front end -as far as I can tell.

However, there are a few problems in the back end. The one that is the most irksome is that admin-ajax.php is not loading anymore preventing us from adding/deteling/editing images and all the other tasks that require this script.

This is what FIREBUG gives me when editing a post and clicking on Add Media:

```
GET http://wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Status: Aborted
Domain: wordpress
Size: 0B
```

Another FIREBUG error:

```
POST http://wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Status: Aborted
Domain: wordpress
Size: 0B
```

There seems to be an error in what wordpress thinks the location of admin-ajax.php is, it should be something like this (right?):

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

It is ignoring, missing, the domain name in admin-ajax.php url.

The question is how to fix this? and, although this is not as important as fixing the issue, how did this happen?

[EDIT]

I don't know if this is related, but I found another issue in the permalinks page of the dashboard:

> Warning: is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/chroot:/home:/tmp:/dev/shm:/usr/share/pear) in /chroot/home/aerostud/mydomain.com/html/wordpress/wp-admin/options-permalink.php on line 130 ...

for what I found online I can correct this adding the proper path to `open_basedir` in php.ini.

Comment: where did you mention adminurl in your code.can you show ?

Comment: Do you have any code or plugins adjusting the output of `get_admin_url()`? http://wpseek.com/get_admin_url/

Comment: Can you provide us url of your site so that we can debug it?

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick replies.
@epilektric, As far as I know the aren't any plugins adjusting the output of get_admin_url(). And I'm using the same plugins I was using before this problem arose. 
@wordpresser, The output of get_admin_url() produces something like this -which is what it is expected: `http://www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin`
@VinodDalvi, I which I could share the url of the site, I have to verify this first, the site is not public yet and the client had me sign a NDA. Would you need access to the back end?

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but I found another issue in the permalinks page of the dashboard:
`Warning: is_writable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/chroot:/home:/tmp:/dev/shm:/usr/share/pear) in /chroot/home/aerostud/mydomain.com/html/wordpress/wp-admin/options-permalink.php on line 130`  ... for what I found online I can correct this adding the proper path to open_basedir in php.ini. Once I tried I'll post here if it affects the load of admin-ajax.php.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was a configuration server problem. The admin turned off `Open_basedir` and all of my headaches, at least on this front, are gone now.

I am not sure what `open_basedir` does exactly, but I think it was originally pointing to a folder outside wordpress, so the Ajax calls in the dashboard were affected by it, which would generate an incorrect path to the Ajax file to load, admin-ajax.php, preventing it from loading.

<sup><sup>***Answer pulled from OP.***</sup></sup>